# Gulp и Bower подключение jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, bower

Что нужно дописать, чтобы Gulp подключал библиотеку jQuery?
Bower установлен. jQuery в `bower_components`, но на странице jQuery не подключен((

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  minCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
bower = require('bower');

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

  browserSync.init({
    server: "app/"
  });

  gulp.watch("app/assets/sass/*.sass", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("app/assets/js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src("app/assets/sass/*.sass")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/assets/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: Вы пробовали подключить jQuery в разметке?

Comment: то есть в любом случае надо вручную подключать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, все равно придется подключать вручную